# How to Code Google Script for Delivery Method on Google Ads based on Time of Day

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm looking for help on coding a google script that will automate a delivery method for Google Ads based on the time of day. For example, I'd like to have an accelerated delivery method during work hours and the standard delivery during 7 PM to 7 AM when traffic is less qualified. Is this possible? Can someone help?

N/A no coding experience thus far

N/A

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't currently change the delivery method through a script. Since you can't create automated rules to change settings either you might have to create duplicates of all your campaigns, one version on accelerated and one on standard and with ad scheduling to turn them on and off at the relevant times.

Although before doing that I'd say you'd need a pretty strong reason, because it'll make everyday management of the accounts pretty messy - especially if you're not on Search Ads 360.